# How to convert Date November 8 2019 to 11/08/19

Tags: sql, oracle

Can you please let me know how do I convert November 8 2019 to 11/08/19 in Oracle SQL Statement

Comment: What have you tried? This [site](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php) may be use to you.

Comment: For this kind of question you must be very explicit with your data types - both for input and for output. Are both the input and the output of `varchar2` data type, or some other, similar **string** data type? Is one of them (or both) in the `date` data type? Also, do you want the output to be a string, or do you want it to be a date but you want the ability to **display** it in the required format? All these are distinct options; the answer depends on *exactly* what you have and what you need.

Comment: sure, let me try with what we have on that site. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Oracle `DATE` type is stored internally as a numeric value (not to be confused with the `NUMBER` type).  Consequently, an Oracle `DATE` has no format and it does not make sense to talk about converting a `DATE` from one format to another.

So, what you are asking about is how to convert a string representation of a particular date from one format to another.  The answer is to first convert the input string to a `DATE` using the input string's format and then convert the resulting `DATE` back to a string using the desired output format.

Like this:

```
select to_char(to_date('November 8 2019','MONTH DD YYYY'),'MM/DD/YY') from dual;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mat, what you said totally make sense now. I could convert my string in the Date format I want.